# Test nested File.open

Tags: ruby

I need to test a file open operation. I am able to test the [first operation](https://github.com/pietbrauer/cocoapods-generate-command/blob/master/lib/pod/command/template_file.rb#L14) but not the [second](https://github.com/pietbrauer/cocoapods-generate-command/blob/master/lib/pod/command/template_file.rb#L16).

```
File.open("#{TemplateFile.fixture_path}/#{@template_file}") do |input_file|
    template = ERB.new(input_file.read)
    File.open("#{@project_name}/#{@destination_file}", 'w') do |output_file|
      output_file.puts template.result binding
    end
  end
end
```

I am using this code:

```
module Pod
  describe TemplateFile do
    it "opens the template" do
      dict = {"README.md.erb" => "README.md"}
      File.expects(:open).with("#{TemplateFile.fixture_path}/README.md.erb")
      File.expects(:open).with("Sample/README.md.erb", 'w')
      TemplateFile.new(dict, "Sample")
    end
  end
end
```

But I am getting an error:

```
unsatisfied expectations:
  - expected exactly once, not yet invoked: File.open('/README.md.erb', 'w')
satisfied expectations:
  - expected exactly once, invoked once: File.open('/lib/pod/command/../../../fixtures/README.md.erb')
```

It seems that Mocha is not geeting the second `File.open`.

Comment: You're using RSpec, right? I've added the "rspec" tag to your question.

Comment: He says he is using Mocha.

Comment: Yes, just Mocha and Bacon.

Comment: Mocha is a JavaScript framework, not a Ruby one. As btype has mentioned "just Mocha and Bacon", I think this is a question about Bacon.

Comment: … which doesn't have a tag. :\

Comment: Yes, that's what I saw too. Seems not so popular.

Comment: Mocha is also a Ruby library and it's the Ruby library btype is using. Bacon is an rspec clone and Mocha is a Mocking/Stubbing library. It isn't as widely used and I would recommend RSpec instead, but the fact is he is using the Ruby library called Mocha with the Ruby testing framework called Bacon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because `expects` verifies the call would happen but doesn't actually let it go through. So what's in the block doesn't get run.

However, beyond just telling you why it's not working, I also wanted to point out what you are doing is probably not what you want to do.

What you likely want to do do is:

```
template = ERB.new(File.read("#{TemplateFile.fixture_path}/#{@template_file}"))
File.open("#{@project_name}/#{@destination_file}", 'w') do |output_file|
  output_file.puts template.result binding
end
```

You don't need that nesting.

Then when testing what you want to do to verify your the correct file is read is:

```
File.expects(:read).with("#{TemplateFile.fixture_path}/README.md.erb").returns(some_known_fixture)
```

The `returns` part says when it does get this `read` method with the specified argument I want you to return this known thing so that `template` will have a good value for the rest of the code.